# Force inactive user to logout

Tags: php, session

I want to logout the inactive user after 5 minutes.

I'm using this code to track the user activities

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 7)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit;
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

but the problem when the time is out it won't destroy the session and redirect him unless the user open or refresh the page

I want to log him out automatically

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no interaction with the server unless the user reloads the page, anything you do here needs to be in Javascript. If it were me I would do an AJAX call to the server periodically to see if the session has expired and then redirect them, once it sees a timeout, to another page. Note that you will have to add header information to stop the page being cached so that the user can't hit the back button (if you really want to stop them viewing the old data).

For IE you need to set quite a lot to stop the caching,.. here is the set of stuff I tend to send as headers in PHP

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' .gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") .' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: Thank you.  I though there's way without using ajax.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: You could run a simple timer in Javascript to avoid AJAX but you can obviously implement a lot more niceties if you refer back to the server